# 'Number Stored as Text' using phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Can someone help me or guide me?

I was using this code.

```
$objPHPExcel
  ->getActiveSheet()
  ->setCellValueExplicit('A1', '1234', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

I need to have a value on excel with `'1234` (declared as Number Stored as Text and hiding the apostrophe)

I already tried to concatenate the apostrophe on the value.

```
$objPHPExcel
  ->getActiveSheet()
  ->setCellValueExplicit('A1', "'"."1234", PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

But it just shows the cell as an ordinary **TEXT**, doesn't declare as **Number Stored as Text**

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to enforce the apostrophe, then you can apply the quotePrefix style setting for the cell (although this shouldn't really be necessary)

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A10')->setQuotePrefix(true);
```

although quotePrefix isn't supported by all Writers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still didn't help me. there still no apostrophe, even though it was already marked as "Number Stored as Text", what i need is the numeric number to have an apostrophe and will be marked as "Number Stored as Text, preceded by an apostrophe" and the apostrophe to be hidden once you open the excel file.

Comment: Then give me some clues..... only the Excel2007 Writer supports quotePrefix, so if you're saving in any other format it won't be there.... for some formats it isn't even practical (CSV, HTML and PDF can never support it)..... so what Writer are you using? and __why__ do you need this?

Comment: My bad, i used Excel 5. Tried using the quotePrefix with Excel2007 and it work. By the way, is there a way(s) to make an excel 5 with quotePrefix? i need it to import the excel to a certain program.

Comment: There isn't, I've never identified the bit settings required for quote prefix style in BIFF-format files..... but it shouldn't be necessary for any importer program to require quote prefix, it's purely a visual style setting for the MS Excel GUI

Comment: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A1', '1234', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);` defines the cell datatype as STRING for SPreadsheet format files..... that should be all you need for any import program

Answer (score -3):

```
$page->setCellValue('A1', ' ' . '12345.67' . ' ');
$page->getStyle('A1')->setQuotePrefix(true);
```

Should work.